# Plone 4.1.4 Site Error: Resource not found

Tags: plone

A little stuck :(Thanks in advance

**Expected Outcome:**

- atitlanorganics.com should render my new plone site.

**Actual Outcome:**

- Site Error: Rource not found

**Stack:**

- Ubuntu sqeeze/sid
- Apache 2.2.14
- Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Mar 12 2012, 20:57:20) [GCC 4.4.3]
- Plone 4.1.4 recently upgrade from 4.1.3
- CMF 2.2.5 Zope 2.13.12
- PIL 1.1.6
- PloneFormgen 1.7.0
- Products.Carousel 2.1
- [Buildout Here: http://pastebin.com/YLBxiTLp](http://pastebin.com/YLBxiTLp)

---

**Troubleshooting:**
Receiving website "Site Error: Resource not found" when i go to: atitlanorganics.com
But works fine when i connect directly to plone: http://72.14.188.28:40000/AtitlanOrganics

When i try to connect directly to atitlanorganics.com I get this error in my browser::

```
> <h2>Site Error</h2> <p>An error was encountered while publishing this
> resource. </p> <p><strong>Resource not found</strong></p> Sorry, the
> requested resource does not exist.<p>Check the URL and try
> again.</p><p><b>Resource:</b> atitlanorganics.com GET</p> <hr
> noshade="noshade"/> <p>Troubleshooting Suggestions</p> <ul> <li>The
> URL may be incorrect.</li> <li>The parameters passed to this resource
> may be incorrect.</li> <li>A resource that this resource relies on may
> be encountering an error.</li> </ul> <p>For more detailed information
> about the error, please refer to the error log. </p> <p>If the error
> persists please contact the site maintainer. Thank you for your
> patience. </p>
```

Apache Access Log::

```
> root@li54-28:/var/log/apache2# tail -n 0 -f access.log
> 
>     > 190.148.214.174 - - [16/Mar/2012:21:54:10 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 792 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0)
> Gecko/20100101
>     > Firefox/11.0"
>     > 190.148.214.174 - - [16/Mar/2012:21:54:12 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 791 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0)
> Gecko/20100101
>     > Firefox/11.0"
>     > 190.148.214.174 - - [16/Mar/2012:21:54:13 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 791 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0)
> Gecko/20100101
>     > Firefox/11.0"
```

Apache Error Log::

```
> root@li54-28:/var/log/apache2# tail -n 0 -f error.log
> ***No errors
```

Plone Console Log:: when directing browser to atitlanorganics.com

```
> shadqudsi@li54-28:~/atitlanorganics.com$ bin/instance fg 2012-03-16
> 21:25:32 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Fri Mar 16 21:25:32 2012
>         Hostname: 0.0.0.0
>         Port: 40000 2012-03-16 21:25:35 WARNING SecurityInfo Conflicting security declarations for "setText" 2012-03-16 21:25:35
> WARNING SecurityInfo Class "ATTopic" had conflicting security
> declarations
> /home/shadqudsi/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py:706:
> UserWarning: The set_schema option of the <requ ire /> directive is
> not supported in Zope 2. Ignored for <class
> 'Products.Carousel.content.carouselbanner.CarouselBanner'>   actions =
> self.handler(context, **args) 2012-03-16 21:25:52 INFO PloneFormGen
> Patching plone.app.portlets ColumnPortletManagerRenderer to not catch
> Retry exceptions 2012-03-16 21:25:53 INFO Zope Ready to handle
> requests
> ***Notice the requests show in the apaches access.log but never in apaches error.log or plones bin/plone fg output
```

Apache site-enabled config for atitlanorganics.com::

```
> root@li54-28:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ll atitlanorganics.com
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 2012-02-13 07:04 atitlanorganics.com ->
> ../sites-available/atitlanorganics.com
> root@li54-28:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled#
> root@li54-28:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# tail atitlanorganics.com
>     <Proxy *>
>         Allow from all
>     </Proxy>  RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:40000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/atitlanorganics.com/VirtualHostRoot/$1
> [P,L]
>     ErrorDocument 503 "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Site down</title></head><h1>Our webmaster isnt very good. Get a rope!</h1>"
> </VirtualHost>
```

Plone Console Log:: when directing browser to http//72.14.188.28:40000/AtitlanOrganics

```
> shadqudsi@li54-28:~/atitlanorganics.com$ bin/instance fg 2012-03-16
> 21:25:32 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Fri Mar 16 21:25:32 2012
>         Hostname: 0.0.0.0
>         Port: 40000 2012-03-16 21:25:35 WARNING SecurityInfo Conflicting security declarations for "setText" 2012-03-16 21:25:35
> WARNING SecurityInfo Class "ATTopic" had conflicting security
> declarations
> /home/shadqudsi/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py:706:
> UserWarning: The set_schema option of the <requ  ire /> directive is
> not supported in Zope 2. Ignored for <class
> 'Products.Carousel.content.carouselbanner.CarouselBanner'>   actions =
> self.handler(context, **args) 2012-03-16 21:25:52 INFO PloneFormGen
> Patching plone.app.portlets ColumnPortletManagerRenderer to not catch
> Retry exceptions 2012-03-16 21:25:53 INFO Zope Ready to handle
> requests 2012-03-16 22:18:04 INFO CMFFormController
> /home/shadqudsi/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7.0-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormfg_base_view_p3.cpt:
> No default action specified for status success, content type ANY. 
> Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in noton
> in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case.
> 
> 2012-03-16 22:18:04 INFO CMFFormController
> /home/shadqudsi/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7.0-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormfg_base_view_p3.cpt:
> No default action specified for status success, content type ANY. 
> Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in noton
> in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case.
```

I diffed my apache sites-enabled atitlanorganics.com config with a know good config of jaibalito.org. The only differences are the directory/domain/port references.

```
> root@li54-28:/etc/apache2/sites-available# diff atitlanorganics.com
> jaibalito.org
> 
> > 2,4c2,4 <       ServerAdmin webmaster@atitlanorganics.com <        
> > ServerName atitlanorganics.com <         ServerAlias
> > www.atitlanorganics.com
> > ---
> > >       ServerAdmin webmaster@jaibalito.org
> > >         ServerName jaibalito.org
> > >         ServerAlias www.jaibalito.org 6c6 <       DocumentRoot /home/shadqudsi/atitlanorganics.com/www
> > ---
> > >       DocumentRoot /home/naderehnilforoushan/jaibalito.org/www 11c11 <       <Directory /home/shadqudsi/atitlanorganics.com/www/>
> > ---
> > >       <Directory /home/naderehnilforoushan/jaibalito.org/www/> 48c48 <     RewriteRule ^(.*)
> > http://127.0.0.1:40000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/atitlanorganics.com/VirtualHostRoot/$1
> > [P,L]
> > ---
> > >     RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1:29000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/jaibalito.org/VirtualHostRoot/$1
> > [P,L] 50c50 <     ErrorDocument 503 "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Site
> > down</title></head><h1>Our webmaster isnt very good. Get a rope!</h1>"
> > ---
> > >     ErrorDocument 503 "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Jaibalito.org Under Repair</title></head><h1>Jaibalito.org under going site
> > maintenance: </h1>"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing us with detailed info! :-)

Comment: Yes!  This is probably the best-written Plone question I've ever seen here - except for the small detail of not including the actual name of your Plone site :-)

Comment: To be honest i was a little nervous posting to an experts forum... I am glad i did! Thanks for the props, I look forward to being a member of this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Solved.**

> We get by with a little help from our friends ;=)

Resolution:
I had a conflict between my Apache "Rewrite rule" and my Plone "Site Name".

Specifically:

```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)
> http://127.0.0.1:40000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/atitlanorganics.com/VirtualHostRoot/$1
```

> `http://72.14.188.28:40000/AtitlanOrganics`

Notice the atitlanorganics.com doesn´t match AtitlanOrganics!! Ah Hah!! I changed my apache config to:

```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)
> http://127.0.0.1:40000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/AtitlanOrganics/VirtualHostRoot/$1
```

Working brilliantly! Peace reigns in Ploniverse once again.

Comment: Since you hadn't told us your Plone site name, it was impossible to know that.  If the jaibalito.org rule works, it seems implied that you're using the same naming scheme for your AtitlanOrganics site (though it would be worth noting that case doesn't matter in a domain name, but certainly does in a Plone site name).

Answer (score 0):

And does your zope have a VirtualHostMonster?

Comment: Yes i do. But i am not using it. to bypass apache?

Comment: I don't understand your question (that is, you have a "?" but it isn't actually a question!).  A VirtualHostMonster is required to make your rewrite rule work.  SO it's the first question that needs to be asked,